# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDates' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo

today i decided to update the dependencies of my react project and my component `Home` didn't work anymore, i'm actually working with a apollo client and apollo react hooks, this is mi `Home` component file:

```
function Home(props) {
    const {
        loading,
        data: { getPosts: posts }
    } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

    return (
        <Grid columns={3} stackable={true} className={loading ? 'loading' : ''}>
            <Grid.Row className='page-title'>
                <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
            </Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Row>
                {user && (
                    <Grid.Column>
                        <PostForm user={user} />
                    </Grid.Column>
                )}
                {loading ? (
                    <Loading />
                ) : (
                    posts &&
                    posts.map(post=> (
                        <Grid.Column key={post._id} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
                            <PostCard post={post} />
                        </Grid.Column>
                    ))
                )}
            </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

and i'm getting this error in the browser:
**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosts' of undefined"**

i'm trying to fix it with this little code variation:

```
function Home(props){
    let posts = '';
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

    if (data) {
        posts = data.getPosts;
    }
```

And everything works fine, but if i add a new Post updating the apollo cache, that cache update correctly with old posts and new post, but the frontend didn't show it, only show old posts until i refresh the page manually.

Edit:
This is the code from the `PostForm` component, i updated the `Home` component too adding the `PostForm`:

```
function PostForm(props) {
    const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(createPostCallback, {
        title: 'Example Title',
        body: ''
    });

    const [createPost] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_MUTATION, {
        variables: values,
        update(dataProxy, result) {
            const data = dataProxy.readQuery({
                query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY
            });
            data.getPosts = [result.data.createPost, ...data.getPosts];
            dataProxy.writeQuery({
                query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
                data
            });
            values.body = '';
        }
    });

    function createPostCallback() {
        createPost();
    }
```

Any idea how to fix the first code issue?
Thanks in advance mates!

Comment: is useQuery a promise?

Comment: its an Apollo-react-hook, like this:
```import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
 const {
  loading,
  data: { getDates: dates }
 } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries for read and write cache in apollo works in a inmutable way. In order to do that, you have to use a new variable, you're using data to write the cache.
Try doing this:

```js
  const [createPost] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_MUTATION, {
    variables: values,
    update (proxy, result) {
      const data = proxy.readQuery({
        query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY
      })
      const new_post = result.data.createPost //here's the new var
      proxy.writeQuery({
        query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
        data: { getPosts: [new_post, ...data.getPosts] } // here you're using that var to write the cache
      })
      values.body = ''
    }
  })
```

Comment: Perfect! works silky and smooth, thanks for your help mate!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed same error with defining data as an object {}
just changed the below code by adding `= {}`

```js
const {
  loading,
  data: { getPosts: posts } = {}
} = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take your `if` statement and set that inside a `useEffect` so it checks 
 if data is a truthy onLoad and so you can sync it to whenever data changes.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
    setPosts(data.getPosts);
  }
},[data])

if (posts.length === 0) {
  return <h3>No posts as of yet</h3>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i've tried your suggestion doing this:
```let posts = '';
 const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
 const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

 useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
   posts = data.getPosts;
  }
 }, [data]);
```

Comment: But it renders with a warning: **"./src/Pages/Home.js
Line 18:12:  Assignments to the 'dates' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render."**

Comment: **"To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"**

Comment: Can you console.log `data.getPosts`? What does that give you?

Comment: That might be an async fetch call. You might need to do something like this if it returns a function:

posts = await data.getPosts()

Comment: Hi Cecil!, if i log ```data.getPost``` obtain an array of posts.

Comment: Hmm have you tried setting that to a local state instead of a post variable? `const [post, setPost] = useState('')` and then `setPosts(data.getPosts)`

Comment: Works, but if y add a new post nothing happens, as always i need to refresh the frontend manually, i going to update my question to show the ```PostForm``` component.

Comment: how about changing the condition from `(data)` to `(data.getPosts.length > 0)` and change the dependency array to `[data.getPosts]`

Comment: that gives this error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDates' of undefined**, check the ```PostForm``` code in my original question and let me know if something of that code is making this issue.

Comment: Can you post your function that adds a new post? And go ahead and set the condition back to `(data)`

Comment: It's defined in this line: ```const [createPost] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_MUTATION, {}```, using a apollo react hook "useMutation".

Comment: is createPost a function? like `createPost(// new post here)`

Comment: The only reason why I ask is if its a function that does a mutation, normally with graphq, you can choose what to return based on the post. If you can return the updated posts, then you can set that to your posts state and have your view updated without the need to do a hard refresh.

Comment: Shure, you checked the ```PostForm``` code added on the original question? in this code you can see all of the ```createPost``` structure, le'me know if you see something wrong there, thanks in advance mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200873/discussion-between-josh-rodriguez-and-cecil-john-tantay).